# Is there a reason why when a parallel-plate setup is immersed under water, the potential difference between them reduces?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, home-experiment

I will elaborate upon this question as follows.

I was trying to devise an experiment to observe equipotential surfaces of different charge configurations, using a movable probe connected to a voltmeter. A very crude circuit diagram would looke like:

[image]

There is a voltmeter, a battery, and two electrodes connected to the battery such that they are immersed in water. A movable probe from the positive terminal of the voltmeter is used to determine the potential of a point in the container of water.

I set the potential difference to be 3V and something baffling happened when I got the equipotential curves. As expected, they were planes, parallel to the plates themselves. However, instead of dropping to 0 at the second plate (it was grounded), it dropped to 1.5 V! Back calculating from the equipotential surfaces using the formula: $$E = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$$ since the potential doesn't vary along the other two axes, I got back an electric field that would be the same if the plates had a potential difference of 1.5 V instead of 3!

How would this be possible, if I actually maintained the potential difference between the plates with a constant power supply of 3V? Incredibly sorry if the question exhibits naivety, but I'd love to know what could be the possible causes.

Some more material-based context if required:

- The plates used were aluminium, of dimensions 15x10 cm. The separation between them was 18 cm. One of my prior concerns was if aluminium oxide was somehow deposited onto the plates, thereby creating some sort of insulation.
- The plates were exactly parallel to one another, and there were no issues there.
- I used tap water, not distilled water - I assume this could be a point of concern since tap water conducts a lot more than distilled water due to dissolved ions.
- The plates were immersed lengthwise (as in, the broader part was immersed), and upto a level of 5 cm.

Please let me know if further details regarding the setup are required. Thanks!

Comment: Did you touch the plate with the probe, or just place the probe close to the plate without touching?

Comment: The probe was just near the plate and didn't touch it; just to check I once touched the electrode which was grounded, and the voltmeter did tell me that it was 0V, which was understandable I feel.

Comment: Yes that is what should be expected. There is fast change of potential on microscopic scale near the plate, due to surface-concentrated ions/charges/dipole layer there.

Comment: I see; thanks. But is there a reason why in the vicinity of the positive electrode a similar effect is not seen - that is, a build up of a dipole layer of sorts?